# Ubuntu restore system scenario

Tags: 18.04, backup

I'm using default ubuntu backup app to backup my:

- /home
- /opt
- /srv
- /usr
- /var
- /snap
- /etc

folders. So let's say my system failed completely or hdd is dead, then i'm going to install Ubuntu and restore these folders from the same application right? But is it going to be enough to keep continue from where i left off? or i should still do a lot of configurations and installations to catch my last system state? I need some advice on this.

Thanks

Comment: just put files you treasure on dropbox,  https://mega.nz, github or any other file sharing tool and upon disaster just go from your notes on how to quickly reinstall an OS from scratch

Comment: As written, this seems impossible to answer. Everyone's backup strategy is a bit different, depending upon the tolerable downtime, restore complexity, and admin skill. For example, I can restore my (simple) desktop system in a half-hour with only a backup of /home...but the server over there uses snapshots. Consider a test restore to find if you have any pain points. That will tell you what *your* backup strategy's problems are.